# To Customize 3.5" Power Panel Elsewhere?

Tags: desktop-computer, clone

I have a small ASUS PC tower where are only two 3.5 slots. 
I need them both for cloning HDDs with two 3.5 slots. 
Therefore, I am thinking how extract the power button from the the 3.5 top panel to elsewhere. 
I think I cannot adjust the whole top panel elsewhere because there is no space at the back side of the PC and only 2.5 slots empty at the front. 
There is not much space left at the back of the PC because having there one GPU (taking two slots) and one WiFi card.

The top panel contains usb hubs, sound hub, microphone hub and power button. 
I can make more cuts in the panel next to 2.5 slots. 
I actually do not need the top panel at all, only the power button.

[image]

---

How can you adjust 3.5 top panel elsewhere in the PC?
Probably in the place of 2.5 slots.

How can you change the interface of the power button? 
Any button which I can order attach somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *physical* panel on the case is probably moulded in, screwed in place, and probably can't be removed. 3.5 inch bays are *typically* internal (Unless you're confusing it with a CD drom/5/25 inch bay), anyway, and if there's a bay behind it you can use it.

The power button itself is a simple momentary switch and you can probably jerry rig one off of an older PC. There are also units that break out the power button and other things. This google search is a [good start](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=power%20button%20external%20PC&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=NPmlVsC_Js2NuATWvaawDA), though the specifics for a external power switch is more in the scope of hardware recommendations.

Cutting the panel is a *terrible* idea.

I've typically just popped the side off of my case, rested my HDDs somewhere safe (I usually place it cover side down, controller board facing up) , and done imaging where needed. Its actually pretty safe and doesn't require ill conceived surgery.

Comment: It is only screwed so I can replace it.